# Checkbox для выбора всех элементов списка (checkbox'ов) используя react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, react-hook

Проблема в том, что checkbox под номером 1 не выделяется, если повторить такие шаги:

1. Нажать "Select all" checkbox
2. Нажать "1" checkbox (чекбокс под номером 1)
3. Нажать "Select all" checkbox

Результат: Чекбок под номером один не выделяется

Пример здесь - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dhys7v

Comment: Вы находитесь на русскоязычном СО. Отредактируйте вопрос (на русский переведите) или он будет закрыт/удалён

Comment: @InDevX, вот только заканчивал писать подобное обращение к пользователю :)))

Comment: Перевел на русский, спасибо за комментарий

Answer (score 1):

Благодаря группе @reactkyiv в телеграм, я смог быстро найти правильное решение.
Решение можно посмотреть здесь - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-47yew7

Comment: Хорошо бы основное в ответ перенести.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду основные моменты, в которых были ошибки?

Comment: Ответы-ссылки у нас не приветствуются. Если вы можете всё решение в ответ перенести - отлично. Если нет, то хотя бы опишите, в чём именно проблема была и как её исправили.